# how to pass login token in headers in other pages in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here i have my upi action folder ,here how can i add my jwt token from login page api to this page. what is the procedure for displaying token genereated from login page to be used in other pages in react.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const upiAction = {
    upi,
};
function upi(user) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        var data = {
            upiId: user.upiId,
            accountNumber: user.accountNumber,
        };
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:9091/upiidcreation', data)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("res", (res));
                alert(JSON.stringify(res.data.responseDesc));
                
                // window.location.pathname = "./homes";
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(setUserUpiError(err, true));
                alert("Please Check With details");
 });
};
}

export function setUserUpi(showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_UPI_SUCCESS',
       showError: showError,
 };
}

export function setUserUpiError(error, showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_UPI_ERROR',
        error: error,
        showError: showError,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import your redux store in any file and then use the getState() function to get the current redux state.

Example:

```
import store from './store'

console.log('Current state: ', store.getState())
// {tokens: [...], otherState: {...}}
```

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#redux-store